# Select-Object -Property returning empty values for certain most properties Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm using the below line of code to get a list of computers from Active Directory and then export them to a CSV file along with certain properties. However, only "SamAccountName" and "DNSHostName" are returning values inside the CSV file. All other properties are empty.

```
Get-ADComputer -filter * | Select-Object -Property SamAccountName,DNSHostName,PasswordLastSet,whenCreated,accountExpirationDate,operatingSystem,operatingSystemServicePack,operatingSystemVersion,userAccountControl,LastLogonDate |export-csv -path "C:\Users\output.csv"
```

When I choose only the property "PasswordLastSet", the CSV file looks odd and returns only true and false as opposed to a date and time. For instance, here are the first three lines:

```
#TYPE Selected.Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADComputer
enabled
TRUE
```

Is there something wrong with the way I'm approaching this?

Comment: when used as you are using it, the `Select-Object` cmdlet **_creates a new object_**. it does NOT filter out properties ... it creates a new object with the named properties. if the name used does not match a property of the input ... that property is created with _nothing in it_. [*grin*] ///// it seems likely your property names in the `Select-Object` line are not exact matches for properties in the source object. ///// also, the `#TYPE` line can be left out by adding `-NoTypeInformation` to your `Export-CSV` call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AD objects like ADComputer have a lot of properties and Get-ADComputer, by default, retrieves just a few of those properties for performance reasons. Use the -properties parameter to specify the properties you need.

```
Get-ADComputer -filter * -Properties SamAccountName,DNSHostName,PasswordLastSet,whenCreated,accountExpirationDate,operatingSystem,operatingSystemServicePack,operatingSystemVersion,userAccountControl,LastLogonDate 
  | Select-Object -Property SamAccountName,DNSHostName,PasswordLastSet,whenCreated,accountExpirationDate,operatingSystem,operatingSystemServicePack,operatingSystemVersion,userAccountControl,LastLogonDate 
  | export-csv -path "C:\Users\output.csv"
```

Use -properties * to get all